# Quick formatted strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, formatting

Is there a quick, easy way of getting sprintf-like formatting when constructing a std::string? Something like...

```
std::string foo("A number (%d) and a character (%c).\n", 18, 'a');
```

Comment: Have a look at my solution. That is C++ Style solution. Doesn't depend on C-style format string involving `%d` and `%c`, like boost.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not built into the string's constructor, but you might want to check out [boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/format/index.html). Its a more typesafe sprintf style string formatting. With it you can at least do this:

```
std::string foo = 
    boost::str(boost::format("A number (%d) and a character (%c)\n") % 18 % 'a');
```

Comment: Place an `uint8_t` instead of literal `18` — and, voila, your Boost output is totally busted: you will receive two characters rather than number with character.

Answer (score 11):

I've written a `stringbuilder` class which you can use and I think that is better than `boost::format` as unlike it, `stringbuilder` does NOT use C-style format string like `%d`, `%c`. etc.

Here is how `stringbuilder` can help you in just one line:

```
std::string s=stringbuilder() << "A number " << 18 <<" and a character " <<'a';
```

The implementation of `stringbuilder` is very simple:

```
struct stringbuilder
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   template<typename T>
   stringbuilder & operator << (const T &data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   operator std::string() { return ss.str(); }
};
```

Demo at ideone :  http://ideone.com/J9ALB

---

I've just written the following blog describing the many different ways of the use of `stringbuilder`.

- [Create string on the fly just in one line](http://thecodingpoint.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-string-on-fly-just-in-one-line.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing :) but I kinda like the C-style formatting syntax better. I personally find the "this is my string, replacing approapiate tokens" approach to formating more comfortable that assembling them piece by piece.

Comment: @Santiago: But you know C-Style formattings are not safe, that is why C++ doesn't use them, and instead came up with `cout` and `cin`, and other stream classes which are safe.

Comment: @Nawaz: Which is also why boost::format was developed, which has printf like formatting and is just as safe as iostream.

Comment: @Benjamin: What if I write `%c` and pass a string?

Comment: @Nawaz: Then boost::format just takes the first character, exactly as it's documentation says it does.

Comment: @Nawaz: once you've wrote internationalized software, you come to love C-formatting style (though with safe approaches...) for the ability to move dynamic bits around in the final translation. IOStream support facets, and they make you pay dearly for it, but it does not help at all with internationalization :/

Comment: @Matthieu: I didn't understand that. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Nawaz: Let's say you want to include an adjective, to the choice of the user. In French, you have the sentence `printf("J'ai vu des oiseaux %s", adjective);` which is fine with a stream: `os << "J'ai vu des oiseaux " << adjective`. In English however, `os << "I have seen birds " << adjective` is incorrect. You need `printf("I have seen %s birds", adjective)`. The sentence is splitted completely differently. In this occurence, you need C-style formatting over stream. (Or you need to change the stream for each language, but that's insane, have a look at gettext to see how resources are handled)

Comment: @Matthieu: Awesome example. Thanks a lot. BTW, how would I know that. I don't know French :P

Comment: @Nawaz: you're out of luck then, I only know French and English :P

Comment: @Matthieu: I've a doubt. In English, why did you not write `os << "I have seen" << adjective << " birds "`, like you did with `printf`?

Comment: @Nawaz: to avoid having a switch(language) in the code for each print statement. The code should be written once, and invoke an external file (typically .po if you use the gettext utility) to get the right sentence depending on the language. And the sentence comes in *one* chunk. Always.

Comment: @Matthieu: One chunk? like `"I have seen %s birds"` or `"J'ai vu des oiseaux %s"`, with the `%s` in it, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: yes, it is easier for translators to provide it as this, because it allows them to reorder the words arbitrarily according to the grammar rules of the language they are targetting.

Comment: @Matthieu: Hmm.. I was guessing exactly that. But wanted to know if you think the same. thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

The [fmt library](http://cppformat.github.io/) provides a safe `sprintf` implementation that returns a string:

```
std::string foo = fmt::sprintf("A number (%d) and a character (%c).\n", 18, 'a');
```

This library also supports Python's [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) syntax:

```
std::string foo = fmt::format("A number ({}) and a character ({}).\n", 18, 'a');
```

It is similar in purpose to Boost Format but is [much faster](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat#speed-tests), pretty small and doesn't have external dependencies other than the standard C++ library.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one, it uses printf directly:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdarg.h> 

std::string format(const char *fmt, ...) 
{ 
    va_list ap; 
    va_start(ap, fmt); 

    const size_t SIZE = 512; 
    char buffer[SIZE] = { 0 }; 
    vsnprintf(buffer, SIZE, fmt, ap); 

    va_end(ap); 

    return std::string(buffer); 
}
```

Comment: Better to look at the `vsnprintf` return value to allocate a right-sized buffer, rather than chopping it off at 512 characters.  Or use [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vasprintf) on Linux.  Also, use [gcc-style function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) so that you still get some type safety on the arguments.